# Near 100% disk usage, df and du show very different results, lsof not the answer

Tags: centos5, disk-space-utilization, lsof, du, df

The issue is that my CentOS 5.8 machine is telling me that I am nearly out of disk space when I am pretty confident this is not the case. I've done a fair amount of researching on this issue and have been unable to find a solution.

'df -h' shows 210G used, 8.6G avail

'ncdu' shows 28.6G used (same for apparent size)

As you can see, this is nearly a 10x difference in the reported 'used' space. Knowing what is stored on this drive, I think 28.6G is closer to reality.

Looking at the output of 'lsof' there are very few lines with (deleted) at the end. Moreover, the largest size of any of these lines is 6190. Finally, I've rebooted the machine a number of times which, if I understand the other threads correctly, would resolve the issue of phantom files anyhow.

Here is a summary of the output from ncdu:

```
   22.7GiB [##########] /opt
    2.8GiB [#         ] /usr
    1.5GiB [          ] /var
  812.4MiB [          ] /root
  310.6MiB [          ] /home
  194.3MiB [          ] /lib
  156.4MiB [          ] /etc
   36.5MiB [          ] /sbin
    7.3MiB [          ] /bin
  128.0KiB [          ] /tmp
   20.0KiB [          ] /mnt
e  16.0KiB [          ] /lost+found
e   8.0KiB [          ] /srv
e   8.0KiB [          ] /selinux
    8.0KiB [          ] /media
e   4.0KiB [          ] /backup
>   0.0  B [          ] /sys
>   0.0  B [          ] /proc
>   0.0  B [          ] /net
>   0.0  B [          ] /misc
>   0.0  B [          ] /dev
>   0.0  B [          ] /boot
    0.0  B [          ]  .autorelabel
    0.0  B [          ]  .autofsck
```

Output of 'df -Th':

```
Filesystem    Type    Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/VolGroup00-LogVol00
              ext3    221G  210G  8.6G  97% /
/dev/sda1     ext3     99M   25M   74M  25% /boot
tmpfs        tmpfs    1.7G     0  1.7G   0% /dev/shm
```

[This post](https://serverfault.com/questions/342961/centos-server-disk-usage-not-matched?s=f66f7139-7a8d-45f4-afea-73a3925654e1) mentions that outside of phantom files there are two other possible explanations:

1. corrupt filesystem
2. compromised machine

I'm looking for help on how to test the validity of these explanations. Obviously, explanation #2 is particularly concerning.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://serverfault.com/questions/57098/du-vs-df-difference

Comment: Are you running `ncdu` with `sudo`?

Comment: This is surprising. Have you finally pinpointed the cause? Or at least some hint? What happened after that?

Comment: And it's not a reserved block count issue? Check with `dumpe2fs`.

Answer (score 1):

You may try running `e2fsck /dev/sdxy` from a live Linux to check for FS corruption. The partition must be unmounted, that's why you need to boot up a live Linux.